# Frida: how to hook a synthetic class

Tags: android, java, frida

When reverse engineering an APK I came across a class that was marked synthetic.
I have used JADX decompiler. The simplified result I got was:

```
package com;

public final class zz6 extends B implements C {
   public /* synthetic */ A(int i, Object obj, Object obj2, Object obj3) {
       ...
   }

   ...
}
```

[Some googling about synthetic java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399546/synthetic-class-in-java) learned me that those classes are generated dynamically.

I hooked this function using Frida and just printed a log when it is called.
When running the app nothing got printed though I'm quite sure the specific function was called.

I wonder if Frida is able to hook these functions or if there are any methods to get a hook on these dynamic functions?

The same constructor function in smali-code:

```
# direct methods
.method public synthetic constructor <init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    .locals 0

    .line 1
    iput p1, p0, Lcom/zz6;->d:I

    iput-object p2, p0, Lcom/zz6;->e:Ljava/lang/Object;

    iput-object p3, p0, Lcom/zz6;->f:Ljava/lang/Object;

    iput-object p4, p0, Lcom/zz6;->g:Ljava/lang/Object;

    const/4 p1, 0x0

    invoke-direct {p0, p1}, Lcom/w54;-><init>(I)V

    return-void
.end method
```

Comment: Have you checked SMALI code in Jadx for the same method? The SMALI methods should be what Frida sees => what should be hookable.

Comment: When I check the SMALI code I can find it. But not sure if this changes anything : # direct methods
.method public synthetic constructor <init>(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    .locals 0

Comment: Don't search for "synthetic", search for the arguments or the method calls in the method (in smali syntax).

Comment: I did not search for this keyword. I searched for the method I wanted to find in the smali code. But I assume you saw that my arguments didnt match the one in my smali code. In my example I edited the arguments, (took arguments from another function). Or do I misinterpret your response?

Comment: It wasn't clear how you searched. so I just wanted to make sure. Some people are deterred by smali code as it is so low-level. And as the function you found is a synthetic constructor but you were searching for a regular method I guessed that you may have just searched for synthetic entries. If you are unable to find a matching method on smali level then it seems that you have to search a different way how to get access to the arguments you want to get access or modify.

Comment: Yes indeed, the example I provided didn't matched the smali-code I gave. 

I once more updated this question to have it matched now and included the full smali constructor.  I understand some people are deterred by smali code but that is not a problem for me, so I can find the right smali code.